# Receiving 403 in ASP.NET WebAPI application when including an extra segment in attribute route

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET WebAPI controller, the following routing setup works correctly:

```
[Route("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

However, when I change the route to `api/catalog/products` I start getting 403 errors when accessing the route. Why would that extra segment cause a 403 error and how can I fix it?

Here is my config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an api folder in the project?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by `when I change the route`. Are you referring to `[Route("api/catalog/products")]` on the controller or are you referring to when you try to browse `api/catalog/products`

Comment: the 403 would happen if you have actual folders that match the requested path.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest you update the attribute routes to follow the suggested format

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController {    
    //GET api/products
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //(Default route)
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

that uses the [`[RoutePrefix]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-prefixes) attribute on the ApiController and adding the [`[Route]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#adding-route-attributes) attribute on the action.

Next, `403 Forbidden` typically occurs when you try to browse to a directory on a site where the Web site does not have the Directory Browsing feature enabled, and the default document is not configured.

In this case you may have an actual folder which is conflicting with the default route of the ProductsController.

when you update the route and try to call `api/catalog/products` it will try to return the actual content of that folder which will fail if the feature is not enabled.

Either remove or rename the folder to something that does not conflict with any of your controller routes.

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)